# Convert project from old version of xcode to newer version

Tags: ios, xcode

Up front: I am new to app development. I am working with xcode 4.6.3, since that is what my older MacBook allows (iOS 10.7.5).

I hope to build an app using 4.6.3, and then in the future (when I can afford to) purchase a new system that will allow me to use the latest (whatever iteration it will then be) xcode.

My question: Is it possible to create an app using an early version of xcode and to later convert to what will be the current version? I realize this suggests a "yes" or "no" answer, but a little more information would be useful.

Thank you,
David

Comment: Using such an old tool can be considered a huge waste of time. So much of the tool, versions of iOS, and the languages have changed too much since Xcode 4.6.3. Xcode 7 is currently in beta.  You will not be able to write an app for the App Store using such an old version of Xcode. Apple requires is devs to stay current.

Comment: I think that many of the methods you use would be deprecated and no longer functional. You would have no choice but to use cocoa and could not take advantage of the new programming language swift. It would take some work to update to the more modern version and, but might give you a head start. For the sake of learning it may be worth it but It is likely to be a large waste of time because what you learn will be outdated. Do it for fun  if you like.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually not use that to deploy an app to the app store because apple requires your app to support 64 bit architecture as of this year. To support that you need a recent version of Xcode (at least 6). Also, the toolchain to actually upload an app to the store changed recently. Get a cheap Mac mini if you have to go on a budget...